# Can't access Apache server via domain from localhost

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, localhost

**Goal**
I'm trying to access my Apache server from localhost without actually using 
`localhost`, but instead with the domain `www.mydomain.com` that it's hosting.

**Problem**
Webbrowser indcates `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, `C#` app gives me `System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:`.

**Important note**
I can access the website from any other computer, both internally on the network and externally from other computers on the internet via domain.

**Reason I need this**
My server software that is developed in `C#` needs to do webrequests to the website (even though it's hosted locally).
When making webrequests I get errors about the certificate due to the domain mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by editing `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
 and changing values of `127.0.0.1` and `::1` from `localhost` to `mydomain.com`.